# Xcode 12 SPM does not fetch packages

Tags: xcode

I've been seriously frustrated with SPM, I am simply unable to fetch packages. Would really appreciate any suggestions you may have.

When I open Xcode project my laptop is unable to resolve SPM packages that does work on another computer.

I get the following error message for every package:

`Missing package product 'Alamofire'`

[image]

If I remove the package and try to add it manually via

- `File > Add Package dependency`
- Put URL: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git
- It then asks me sign in with Github account (even I have already added Github Account to Xcode and this is public repository).
- After logging in it asks me to input version and upon clicking Next says "The repository could not be found. Make sure a valid repository exists at the specified location and try again."

Comment: A couple of troubleshooting ideas: 1. Try adding the package to a fresh project. 2. If that doesn't work, try creating a temporary account and see if you can add the package to a new project while logged into the temp account.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! Adding the package in new project gives same error on my account. However, if I create new user account on my computer then everything works! Any ideas what can I do to fix my current account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with clearing `~/.ssh/config`. I had removed line which forced ssh connection.

Comment: please how do I find the ~/.ssh/config?